# Proving lower bound by proving not little o

Tags: time-complexity, lower-bounds

I have been reading these [distributed computing notes](https://disco.ethz.ch/courses/podc/lecturenotes/DGA.pdf). In some of the proofs, for proving lower bound of $\Omega(f(n))$, we prove that no algorithm which solves the problem in $o(f(n))$ exists.

I can't see how not having a $o(f(n))$ algorithm proves the lower bound is $\Omega(f(n))$.

I tried using the definitions, but not having an $o(f(n))$ algorithm implies, for all algorithms $\exists c>0 $ such that $\forall n_0 \exists n \geq n_0$ such that there exists an input of size $n$ which takes at least time $cf(n)$.

For $\Omega(f(n))$, we would require $\exists c>0,n_0 $ such that $\forall n \geq n_0$ there exists an input of size $n$ which takes at least time $cf(n)$.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your confusion is completely justified.

When we say that some problem $A$ has a lower bound of $\Omega(f(n))$ usually we mean that "No algorithm that runs in time $o(f(n))$ solves $A$" or equivalently, "there is an infinite class of instances for which any algorithm that solves $A$ requires time at least $cf(n)$ for some constant $c>0$".

This matches the [Hardy-Littlewood version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations) of the $\Omega(\cdot)$ notation.

This is in contrast with "any algorithm that solves $A$ requires time at least $cf(n)$ on all sufficiently large instances", which is what you were expecting.